# integration of google ads in an expandable list view adapter (BaseExpandableView)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, listview

how do I add google ads in an expandable list view adapter (BaseExpandableView) ?

what i have done  -> added the addview in the xml layout of parentView (issue - working but not expanding).

what i want as fully working approach -> independent addview as a parent which i can interchange with even no. of positions .

here is the code ->

```
class RecordExpandableListAdapterCllRcc(
val mContext: Context,
private val viewModelCllRcc: RecordHistoryViewModelCllRcc,
private val lifecycleOwnerCllRcc: LifecycleOwner): BaseExpandableListAdapter() {

var recordsListCllRccCllRcc: MutableList<RecordCllRcc> = mutableListOf()
    set(valueCllRcc) {
        field = valueCllRcc
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
    return recordsListCllRccCllRcc.size
}

override fun getChildrenCount(groupPositionCllRcc: Int): Int = 1

override fun getGroup(groupPositionCllRcc: Int): RecordCllRcc {
    return recordsListCllRccCllRcc[groupPositionCllRcc]
}

override fun getChild(groupPositionCllRcc: Int, childPositionCllRcc: Int): RecordCllRcc =
    recordsListCllRccCllRcc[groupPositionCllRcc]

override fun getGroupId(groupPositionCllRcc: Int): Long = groupPositionCllRcc.toLong()

override fun getChildId(groupPositionCllRcc: Int, childPositionCllRcc: Int): Long {

    return childPositionCllRcc.toLong()
}
override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
    return true
}

override fun getGroupView(
    groupPositionCllRcc: Int,
    isExpandedCllRcc: Boolean,
    convertViewCllRcc: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup?
): View {



    val bindingCllRcc: ListItemRecordCllRccBinding = if (convertViewCllRcc == null) {


        DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context),
            R.layout.list_item_record_cll_rcc,
            parent,
            false
        )


    } else {

        DataBindingUtil.getBinding(convertViewCllRcc)!!
    }

    bindRecordCllRcc(bindingCllRcc, groupPositionCllRcc)

    return bindingCllRcc.root
}

private fun bindRecordCllRcc(
    bindingCllRcc: ListItemRecordCllRccBinding,
    groupPositionCllRcc: Int
) {

    bindingCllRcc.record = getGroup(groupPositionCllRcc)

    if (groupPositionCllRcc%4 ==3 ){
        bindingCllRcc.nativeAd.visibility = VISIBLE

        val adLoader = AdLoader.Builder(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.native_ad_id))
            .forNativeAd { ad : NativeAd ->
                bindingCllRcc.templateID.setNativeAd(ad)
            }
            .withAdListener(object : AdListener() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                    Log.e("",adError.message)
                    // Handle the failure by logging, altering the UI, and so on.
                }

                override fun onAdLoaded() {
                    Log.e("","add loaded")
                    super.onAdLoaded()
                }
            })
            .withNativeAdOptions(NativeAdOptions.Builder()
                // Methods in the NativeAdOptions.Builder class can be
                // used here to specify individual options settings.
                .build())
            .build()
        adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())

    }

    when (groupPositionCllRcc){
        0->bindingCllRcc.isFirstOrLastItem = true
        else -> bindingCllRcc.isFirstOrLastItem = false
    }

}

override fun onGroupCollapsed(groupPositionCllRcc: Int) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPositionCllRcc) //        pos = groupPosition
}

override fun getChildView(
    groupPositionCllRcc: Int,
    childPositionCllRcc: Int,
    isLastChildCllRcc: Boolean,
    convertViewCllRcc: View?,
    parent: ViewGroup
): View {
    val bindingCllRcc: ListItemExpandedRecordBinding = if (convertViewCllRcc == null) {
        DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            R.layout.list_item_expanded_record,
            parent,
            false
        )
    } else {
        DataBindingUtil.getBinding(convertViewCllRcc)!!
    }
    Log.e("position"," $groupPositionCllRcc $childPositionCllRcc")
    bindExpandedViewCllRcc(bindingCllRcc, groupPositionCllRcc, childPositionCllRcc)

    return bindingCllRcc.root
}

private fun bindExpandedViewCllRcc(
    binding: ListItemExpandedRecordBinding,
    groupPositionCllRcc: Int,
    childPositionCllRcc: Int
) {
    try {


        val recordCllRcc = getChild(groupPositionCllRcc, childPositionCllRcc)
        val fileCllRcc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString() + "/Call/" + recordCllRcc.nameCllRcc

        binding.viewModel = viewModelCllRcc
        if (viewModelCllRcc.currentRecordCllRcc.value?.nameCllRcc != recordCllRcc.nameCllRcc) {
            binding.record = recordCllRcc
            viewModelCllRcc.currentRecordCllRcc.value = recordCllRcc
        }



        binding.wave.setRawDataCllRcc(File(fileCllRcc).readBytes()) { }
        binding.wave.onProgressListenerCllRcc = object : CustomProgressListenerCllRcc() {
            override fun onProgressChanged(progress: Float, byUser: Boolean) {
                if (byUser) {
                    viewModelCllRcc.seekToCllRcc(progress, recordCllRcc)
                }
            }
        }
        viewModelCllRcc.currentPositionCllRcc.observe(lifecycleOwnerCllRcc) {
            binding.redLineSeekBar.translationX = (binding.wave.width * it.toFloat()) / 101.5f
        }
        viewModelCllRcc.isPlayingCllRcc.observe(lifecycleOwnerCllRcc) {
            binding.isPlaying = it
        }
    } catch (eCllRcc: Exception) {
        eCllRcc.printStackTrace()
    }
}
override fun isChildSelectable(p0CllRcc: Int, p1CllRcc: Int): 
Boolean = false
 }
```